# Case statement in LEFT OUTER JOIN slowing the query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, left-join

I am getting a problem with my LEFT OUTER JOIN. I have a set of queries which gives me about 80,000 to 1,00000 records in a #Temp Table. Now when I LEFT OUTER JOIN this #Temp table with another table I have to put a CASE statement i.e. if the records are not found when  joining with a particular column then take that particular column value and find its subsequent value in another table which has the matching records. The query is working fine for a particular data but for larger data it just goes on executing or just takes too much time. My query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 ON #Temp.Materialcode = 
     CASE WHEN TABLE1.MaterialCode LIKE 'HY%' 
               THEN TABLE1.MaterialCode 
               ELSE REPLACE(TABLE1.MaterialCode,
                            TABLE1.MaterialCode,
                            (SELECT NewMaterialCode 
                                    FROM TABLE2 
                                    WHERE OldMaterialCode = TABLE1.MaterialCode))
     END
```

Here TABLE2 has got only two columns NewMaterialCode and OldMetarialCode. What I have to do is if the Material Code is not found in TABLE1  LIKE 'HY%' type then it should take that material code and look for its subsequent NewMaterialCode in TABLE2 to get both types of records having 'HY' type and non 'HY' type.  I think I made my problem clear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The logic of your query is not as you describe - rather than looking up on TABLE2 where no record is found on TABLE1 (which is what you said the query does), the query is actually looking up NewMaterialCode values on TABLE2 where the TABLE1 MaterialCode value is not like `HY%`, and then linking to records on TABLE1 where the #Temp.Materialcode value matches the TABLE2.NewMaterialCode value.

Comment: Is this a query that you wrote, or one written by someone else that you need to maintain? If it's the former, then you have written it incorrectly for your requirements; if it is the latter, then it is not doing what you think. Do you want an amended query to match the requirements you described, or to replicate the existing functionality?

Comment: Yes I have to modify this query. The output should be like I should get all the records having the HY% MaterialCode and also the other MaterialCodes. An amended query would be great.

Comment: You haven't answered either of my questions. We know you have to modify this query, otherwise you wouldn't be posting it here. I repeat: **do you want an amended query to match the requirements you described, or to replicate the existing functionality?**

Comment: I want an amended query to match the requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
   FROM #TEMP TMP
        LEFT JOIN Table1 MATERIAL
          ON TMP.MaterialCode = MATERIAL.MaterialCode
        LEFT JOIN Table2 REPLACEMENT
          ON MATERIAL.MaterialCode = REPLACEMENT.OldMaterialCode
   WHERE (        COALESCE(MATERIAL.materialcode, '') LIKE 'HY%'
              AND TMP.materialCode  = MATERIAL.MaterialCode
         )
      OR MATERIAL.MaterialCode =  REPLACEMENT.NewMaterialCode
```

I think this should do what you're trying to do, but I don't really know how the tables are related except by reverse-engineering your query.

For the record, the OUTER JOIN in your query isn't accomplishing a thing, because an outer condition would product null values for the columns in TABLE1, and the case condition wouldn't work   (a NULL would be neither a match for 'HY%' *nor* an ELSE).   That's counter-intuitive to those not used to working in the three-valued logic of the database world, but that's why we have `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`.

Comment: But I cannot use WHERE condition here because I have to add the Parameters in the Stored Procedure as filters here in the Where Condition.

Comment: Add any additional clauses to the WHERE clause using `AND`.